# Make JTextField keep same size as JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, miglayout

I have a JTable with four columns. Above each of these columns I want a JTextField or something similar, with the intention of having the input filter the respective column. Let's say for clarification that the second column is called "Names", if you write "John" in the second JTextField you're supposed to filter the JTable as to show the names that begin with John, ie. John; Johnny, or if you write "Joh" you might see John; Johnny; Johanna.

My problem is not mainly the filtering in itself but rather how to link the size of the JTextFields to the columnsize. While I can obviously have the same size when the program starts, I want the JTextField(s) to adjust itself if the user resizes one of the JTable columns (most likely several TextFields have to be resized every time you resize a column, as the resizing of one column results in the other columns adjusting to fit the JTable size)

I'm using Netbeans GUI editor for now but once I've written the component logic I will most likely do it all in MigLayout, if that makes a difference. Any tips on how to best implement this?

Comment: You could use a `GridLayout`, but you might find making your own `LayoutManager` which works with the `JTable`'s `ColumnModel` a easier solution

Answer (score 0):

use a `TableModelListener` to check if the size of any column got changed:

```
table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {

    @Override
    public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        TableColumn c = ((TableColumn) e.getSource());
        //some logic to resize the right textfield
        textfieldxyz.setWidt(c.getWidth());
    }

    @Override
    public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

now you only have to determine which column was resized and react to it properly